# How to give command line arguments as questions in Grunt

Tags: javascript, build, gruntjs

I am giving in command line parameters to grunt like this

```
grunt deploy --minify=false
```

But is it possible to do it in the following way. I will just say grunt deploy and press enter, the options should be asked as questions. For example,

when I say

```
grunt deploy
```

and press enter, it should ask me

```
Do you want to minify :
```

Then i will type true/false and press enter. And my grunt task should run.

Is it possible to add multiple parameters like this as questions?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you probably have to write your own grunt task entirely. One interactive prompt-dialog library that I know to be used in many node tools is [InquirerJS](https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js/).

If you follow the examples on the github page, it should be easy enough to turn it into a custom grunt task.